# Not able to deploy project

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish

I have data base connection which i have configured via a listener class i configured properly 
    in DD

```
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

   <listener>
        <listener-class>contpack.startL</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>username</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>password</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>url</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hell</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.contpack.Dbc</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hell</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Dbc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

but still i am not able to deploy the project and server log show that startL.java listener class was not found why is this so as config is proper with the name
and the listener class is:

```
        package com.contpack;

        import javax.servlet.*;
        import javax.servlet.http.*;
        import model.Database;


        public class startL implements ServletContextListener {

        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
        {
                ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
                String url = sc.getInitParameter("url");
                String user_name = sc.getInitParameter("username");
                String password = sc.getInitParameter("password");
             //   String database = sc.getInitParameter("database");
                Database db = new Database(url,user_name,password);
            //System.out.println("in the listener!!");
                sc.setAttribute("db", db);

        }

        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
        {

        }
    }
```

The stack trace for server Log is:

```
    [2014-08-01T20:53:59.112+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] 
    [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)]
    [timeMillis: 1406906639112] [levelValue: 1000]
    [[Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: contpack.startL.java]]
```

**if i remove the Listener tag then app runs fine**

Comment: post the web.xml and the listener class no image please

Comment: Try to follow java naming convention for your listener class

Comment: @Nik6019 hi sorry dint see your message btw `jjd` very well gave you the answer your pacage name is `com.contpack` so change `<listener-class>contpack.startL</listener-class>` to <listener-class>com.contpack.startL</listener-class>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>contpack.startL</listener-class>
</listener>
...
```

and your listener is in the package

```
package com.contpack;
```

that means your listener fully qualified name is

```
com.contpack.startL
```

So setting a correct listener class will help. Your web.xml should look like the following

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.contpack.startL</listener-class>
</listener>
...
```

Still it is always a good idea to follow java naming convention